# Size of video file generated using ffmpeg is alot, what can I do for it?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, video, ffmpeg

So, I am trying to build a kind of a video\audio editor for android and ios using FFMPEG and Flutter. I generate a video by combining an image and an audio file. Now, I plan to use FFmpeg filters like showwaves to display audio visualization and overlay it on the video generated previously. But the file size is increasing dramatically after doing this. Supposedly, if the audio was 2 MB, the video generated after audio visualization is 180 MB. Can I reduce the size of the file without sacrificing the video quality? If yes, how?

Here is the command used to add audio visualization:

> ffmpeg -y -i "input.mp3" -filter_complex
> "[0:a]showwaves=mode=cline:s=1920x1080[v]" -map '[v]' -map '0:a' -c:a
> copy "output.mp4"

Any help is more than welcome, thank you.

Also, I noticed that if I use Shotcut video editor, the file generated is only 200kb in size. How can I replicate it?
PS. Is there a way to reduce the time it takes to complete these operations because the time it takes to generate the audio visualization is also a lot, it annoys me, so I guess even users would be annoyed.

Comment: Maybe you can check the H265 format for mpeg videos (check the documentation to see if it meets your requirements). You can add the following arguments: "-vcodec libx265 -crf 28".

Comment: Ok will check it out ASAP.